# Execute command inside datareader c#

Tags: c#

I have a button click function which runs a stored procedure.

The stored procedure returns data. After execution depend upon the datareader output another command needs to be executed.

```
using (SqlDataReader oReader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (oReader.Read())
    {
        if (oReader["comments1"].ToString() == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CHECK THE COMMENTS AND THE GIVEN VALUE");
            ;
        }
        else
        {

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted data");
            ClearTextBoxes(this);
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first

I know that im trying to use same connection for reading and also for writing the data in the table.

Whether there is any other approach to solve the given problem.

Entire Function:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"[lis1].[_Submit_test]", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = textBox1.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox11.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@workflow", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox2.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@program", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Full_Denial", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Partial_Denial", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox3.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@No_Findings", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox4.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Rejections", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox5.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Unfulfilled", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox6.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@TargetPerDay", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox7.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Audits_Assigned", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox10.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Total_Audits_Reviewed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox12.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Audits_Carry_Forward", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox8.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Pending_Audits", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox9.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Comments", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox3.Text;

            SqlParameter returnParameter = command.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
            returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            using (SqlDataReader oReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (oReader.Read())
                {
                    if (oReader["comments1"].ToString() == "0")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("CHECK THE COMMENTS AND THE GIVEN VALUE");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Inserted data");
                        ClearTextBoxes(this);
                        button2.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a new connection and command and use that.

Comment: What will you want to do when `oReader["comments1"].ToString() != "0";`

Comment: Side note: `command.Parameters.Add("@Unfulfilled", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox6.Text;` The assigned type is a string here, convert that to an `int` in the assignment if that is the type in Sql Server.

Comment: @D-Shih if oReader["comments1"].ToString() != "0" then execute the stored procedure [lis1].[_Submit_test]

Comment: Would that help if you enable Multiple Active Result Sets? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call `command.ExecuteReader` and `command.ExecuteNonQuery` on the same `command` object.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I tried to execute same command using  command.ExecuteReader() and using command.ExecuteNonQuery() after i removed the command.ExecuteNonQuery(). Everything works as i expected.

```
 using (SqlDataReader oReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (oReader.Read())
                        {
                            if (oReader["comments1"].ToString() == "0")
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("CHECK THE COMMENTS AND THE GIVEN VALUE");
                                ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
                                ClearTextBoxes(this);
                                button2.Enabled = false;
                            }



                        }
```